# jQuery keyup changes color but after that it changes again to the original one

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

i am trying to change the color of the current `<tr>` selected, navigating with the **key up** and **key down** of the keyboard.

The shows are result of an Ajax request and the result is a table with **n** rows. Each row is the name of the show. I put the table below the input field (to search).

Input field:

```
<form action="/Search" method="post">
    <input id="search" class="search-input" type="text" name="query" title="Search" autocomplete="off">
</form>
</div>
```

Table with results:

```
<div id="search_results"><table class="autocomplete">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/Shows/Details/Breaking%20Bad">Breaking Bad</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/Shows/Details/Prison%20Break">Prison Break</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table></div>
```

Here is the code that I am using to change the color of the rows:

```
$("#search").keyup(function (e) {
                    if (e.which == 40) {
                            $("#search_results tr:nth-child(1)").css("background", "#D6D6FF");
                    }
                });
```

The problem is that it does change the color but after 1 second, it changes to the original one. I saw some examples and i think this should work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/cnq4u/

Comment: Maybe table's `contents` are being replaced by ajax autocomplete script `every 1 second`.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/M6Mrf/1/. color is not changed in the original one even after a minute.

Comment: Joy you are right. I put an alert on the success fucntion and when i click on down key, it does another ajax request. Thank you so much!

Comment: shouldn't it be `.css("background-color", "#d6d6ff")`?  thought `.css` didn't work for shorthands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think I got it.

```
var currentChild = 0;

$("#search").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 40) {
        if ($("#search_results tr:nth-child(" + currentChild+++")").length == 0) currentChild = 1;
        $("#search_results tr").css("background", "");

        $("#search_results tr:nth-child(" + currentChild + ")").css("background", "#D6D6FF");
    } else if (e.which == 38) {
        if ($("#search_results tr:nth-child(" + currentChild-- +")").length == 0) currentChild++;
        $("#search_results tr").css("background", "");

        $("#search_results tr:nth-child(" + currentChild + ")").css("background", "#D6D6FF");

    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/M6Mrf/5/

Comment: Well, at least I got the javascript code. Perhaps we need to see the ajax code.

Comment: On the jsfiddle it doesn't work, but on my project does. Now that i fixed the ajax requests (only for letters and numbers), it works just fine, thanks.